# Node js - React : Fetching API request does not return any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to `fetch` an API request to obtain some information of research vessels.
I am trying to use the API from [AIS Hub](http://www.aishub.net/api). After following their documentation and applying simple request such as:

```
http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=1
```

I am still not able to obtain any data in return.
After launching a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` on my terminal I obtain the following output:

> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2020 12:16:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2020 12:16:16] "GET /boat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2020 12:16:16] "GET /boat.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I know that at this point the `fetch` is probably not working. I am also not sure if I am putting correctly the request. If that useful [here](http://www.aishub.net/api) is the Sample tab that shows how data are structured.

Below the sample code I am using:

```
const btnSearch = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
const txtSearch = document.getElementById('boat');
const resultArea = document.getElementById('result');
let out = '';

btnSearch.onClick = function() {
    var searchTerm = txtSearch.value;
    const url = `http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6=${searchTerm}`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonObject) {
            console.log('Read This??????');
            console.log(jsonObject);
            for (boat in jsonObject) {
                const boatInfo = new Array(
                    jsonObject[boat].mmsi,
                    jsonObject[boat].time,
                    jsonObject[boat].longitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].latitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].cog,
                    jsonObject[boat].sog,
                    jsonObject[boat].heading,
                    jsonObject[boat].navsat,
                    jsonObject[boat].imo,
                    jsonObject[boat].name,
                    jsonObject[boat].callsign,
                    jsonObject[boat].type,
                    jsonObject[boat].a,
                    jsonObject[boat].b,
                    jsonObject[boat].c,
                    jsonObject[boat].d,
                    jsonObject[boat].draught,
                    jsonObject[boat].dest,
                    jsonObject[boat].eta
                );
                boatOut(boatInfo);
                console.log(boatInfo);
            }
            resultArea.innerHTML = out;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('Error' + e);
        });
};

function boatOut(boat) {
    console.log(boat);
    out += `<div class="boat">
            <div class="boatText">
            <h2>${boat[9]}</h2>
            <h3>${boat[1]}</h3>
            <p><em>${boat[8]}</em></p>
            </div><!-- boatText -->
            </div><!-- boat -->`;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

I was researching on the [official documentation](http://www.aishub.net/api) and tried different combination of the API listed. I was trying to look for potential examples online but I could not find anything in particular. The way this API works is a little bit difficult for me to understand because it is different from the usual type that is possible to find for other applications (e.g. recipes, food etc).
I am running out of ideas as I don't know what else to try.
Thanks if someone already found in this situation and that can point to the right direction to solve the issue.

Comment: does it work with actual browser?

Comment: @FlashThunder, thanks for reading the question. Unfortunately it does not. [here](https://i.imgur.com/RWbkceL.png) I tried to look for MMSI number but returned nothing.

Comment: sorry, I'm too tired right now, but will look at it tomorrow, if it will be still unanswered (added to bookmarks)

Comment: :) Hey don't worry! Thanks again for reading though! Have a good evening! If I find the problem I will post the solution.

Comment: Are you missing an ampersand and definition where I put the ????  `const url = http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6` ???? `=${searchTerm};`

Comment: @RobMoll, thanks for reading. what do you mean? What am I missing? What would the modified code be?

Comment: Something like this: `const url = http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6` **&searchTerm** `=${searchTerm};`

Comment: I tried this: `const url = http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=My_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6&searchTerm=${searchTerm}`;

Comment: But that did not work, if I understood what you were suggesting correctly.

Comment: Upon further review It looks like you are just reading data from that api so I don't think you need to pass the search term at all. So maybe this: `const url = http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6;`  I took out the searchterm portion.

Comment: Thanks but still does not fetch any data. if I `console.log("Pass here?")` before and after the `url` I get no answer too.

Comment: Oh - that's important. I just checked and onClick is no good. Needs to be lowercase in js. Please try that. But you definitely don't want that last param in your url.

Comment: and is the problem fixed? I came back as I promised

Comment: @FlashThunder, :) thanks so much for the message and checking in :) ! Unfortunately it is still not working, despite the additional advises. Maybe I could share a Bitbucket if you would like to take a glance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of issues. The url appears to be malformed. I see you're using a test url from the "official document" link you provided. Please remove the template literal from the end of the url. Your url looks like this:  `const url = http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6=${searchTerm};`  I removed the backticks for formatting reasons. Once you remove the template literal you will no longer need backticks and can switch to quotes.  Now your url should look like this: `const url = "http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=USERNAME&format=1&output=json&compress=3&latmin=20.5&latmax=30.8&lonmin=-15&lonmax=18.6";`  It appears based on the comments that your onclick function is never running. This is due to using camel case in onclick. You have:  `btnSearch.onClick = function() {`. Please change that to `btnSearch.onclick = function() {` Notice that onClick is now onclick. When using onclick in js it must be all lowercase.

Comment: I see you implemented the changes I show in my answer. They contribute as much to your solution as your answer does. Would you kindly upvote this answer? Remember that an upvote only indicates that "This answer is useful." If you truly feel this answer was not useful, let me know so I can delete it. Thanks - I'm glad you (we) got this worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question and will post it so that it could benefit others. The problem I had was that a `GET` request had to be implemented otherwise nothing would be received. Below the working code if anyone needs:

```
const btnSearch = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
const txtSearch = document.getElementById('boat');
const resultArea = document.getElementById('result');
let out = '';

const fetchConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors'
};

btnSearch.onclick = function() {
    var searchTerm = txtSearch.value;
    const url = 'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=My_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=1';
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url, fetchConfig)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonObject) {
            console.log('Read This??????');
            console.log(jsonObject);
            for (boat in jsonObject) {
                const boatInfo = [
                    jsonObject[boat].mmsi,
                    jsonObject[boat].time,
                    jsonObject[boat].longitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].latitude,
                    jsonObject[boat].cog,
                    jsonObject[boat].sog,
                    jsonObject[boat].heading,
                    jsonObject[boat].navsat,
                    jsonObject[boat].imo,
                    jsonObject[boat].name,
                    jsonObject[boat].callsign,
                    jsonObject[boat].type,
                    jsonObject[boat].a,
                    jsonObject[boat].b,
                    jsonObject[boat].c,
                    jsonObject[boat].d,
                    jsonObject[boat].draught,
                    jsonObject[boat].dest,
                    jsonObject[boat].eta
                ];
                boatOut(boatInfo);
                console.log(boatInfo);
            }
            resultArea.innerHTML = out;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('Error' + e);
        });
};

function boatOut(boat) {
    console.log(boat);
    out += `<div class="boat">
            <div class="boatText">
            <h2>${boat[0]}</h2>
            <h3>${boat[0]}</h3>
            <p><em>${boat[0]}</em></p>
            </div><!-- boatText -->
            </div><!-- boat -->`;
}
```